# How to prevent opening a new tab when clicked on link in ReactJs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
 RenderByTenantFunc({
            wp: () => (
              <Tooltip id="tooltip-fab" title="Home">
                <Button className="home-button">
                  <a
                    href={
                    GAIN_ENV.toLowerCase() === 'staging'
                      ? 'link1'
                      : 'link2'
                  }
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                    <div aria-label={translate('home')}>
                      <img
                        className="icon"
                        style={{
                          width: '22px',
                          height: '20px',
                          marginBottom: '-10px',
                        }}
                        src={SourceWpIcon}
                        alt={translate('home')}
                      />
                      <span className="home-button-text">Home</span>
                    </div>
                  </a>
                </Button>
              </Tooltip>
            ),
          })
```

If you are clicking on the Home button a new browser tab opens.  This is very confusing to customers as they think they're being taken somewhere else.   It should direct to the navigation selection in the same browser tab. I tried by removing **target="_blank"**, but still navigating to a new browser, I was stuck here, please help me, guys.

Answer (score 0):

the default value of target is _blank try with changing it to _self